# Gradle build to copy jars to Maven Local Repository

Tags: java, gradle

When building this gradle https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/master/build.gradle

Using: `./gradle build`

And results to

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8m 36s
161 actionable tasks: 61 executed, 100 up-to-date
```

However jars are not copied to the Local maven repository path: `/.m2/`

What can be done here to make sure it deploys to local maven repository?

Comment: Did you try `gradle install`? The project uses the old (and deprecated) publishing mechanism as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html).

Comment: @LukasKörfer yes but getting errors: https://gist.github.com/questionaut/268c0b059c00b43730115e20a028eead

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, create a jar file and push it into the local repository.

I fixed the issue by doing this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '2.2'
description = 'myproject'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Gradle-7.5 version.

You need to add maven-push plugin and publishing it. Also the command is:

```
./gradlew clean build publishToMavenLocal
```